# Looking up values in cells from 2 different spreadsheets and returning a Y or N value

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, if 1 cell contains value (IP Address), and 1 cell in another spreadsheet has that value, but not JUST that value (example: RSServer IP Address Location), I would like to return a response of "Y" or "N" depending on if it finds the value from the first spreadsheet on the 2nd spreadsheet.

Example: 
Spreadsheet 1 named IP Addresses
Column G
Cell G2 Value: 192.38.111.22

Spreadsheet 2 named Server Locations
Column F
Cell F2 Value: DVRLocation 192.38.111.22 New York

Spreadsheet 2 has 60,000 rows that I need to check to ensure the IP Address in Spreadsheet 1 is present. If it is, then I want to return a value of Y in the first spreadsheet in H2.

I hope I was clear enough, and I appreciate any input! I'm a VBA beginner but consider myself fluent in Excel. Thank you!!!!

Comment: So you need to check over all rows, or just corresponding rows?  If G2 contains `192.38.111.22` in Spreadsheet 1, does it matter where it is in Spreadsheet 2?  Can it be in only G2, or anywhere (say, G12557)?

Comment: Thanks John. I only need to search the "F" column in spreadsheet 2, but could be any cell in that column, not just F2, but yes it could be F12557, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about vb, but the formula I'm pretty sure can be translated there.

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&'Spreadsheet 1'!G2&"*",'Spreadsheet 2'!F:Y,20,0)
```

To get a `Y`/`N` result:

```
=IF(ISERROR(COUNTIF('Spreadsheet 2'!F:F, "*"&'Spreadsheet 1'!G2&"*")),"N","Y")
```

Or using vlookup:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&'Spreadsheet 1'!G2&"*",'Spreadsheet 2'!F:F,1,0)),"N","Y")
```

Comment: Ok I see your formula, and thank you so much for answering my question. Towards the end of it, there is an F:Y,20,0. I see the F: is for all the rows in "F" and the Y is to respond to my question having it return a "N" or "Y" in H2 on the first spreadsheet, but what does the 20,0 represent?

Comment: I used your formula, but looking at it, I think the wildcards are in the wrong section (and I can't seem to add them). I MAY BE WRONG, so I apologize ahead of time, but the wildcards would be in the 2nd spreadsheet because I need to search for the IP Address in the first sheet throughout the whole column of F in the 2nd spreadsheet. Here's what I altered:                                                                                                                                `code`=VLOOKUP("*"&[APT.xls]Sheet1!G2&"*",[VOD.xlsx]Sheet1!F:Y,20,0)`/code`

Comment: @user1202310: Oh, then you might use an `if()` and `countif()` which could a bit faster, or use an if with the `vlookup()` and an `iserror()` function. I will add that formula in a bit. To your second comment, what vlookup does is compare the first parameter with each of the table contents, so that it will look for `*192.38.111.22*` in the second sheet, and that's where the wildcards come into play. I'm really not sure how this works out in vb :S

Comment: I'm definitely ok without using VBA. It's much more complex than I need it to be. I just added the macro @chancea gave me and it says "Subscript out of range" which means I probably fudged something up. I'll be happy to wait for your formula if it's easier. FYI, the name with the single IP Address is APT.xls and the name of the 2nd sheet with mass amounts of data, including the IP Address, is VOD.xlsx if that helps with the formula thank you!!!!!!!!

Comment: This worked! Thank you SO MUCH for your help @chancea and John this worked perfectly! I used the Y/N result and ISERROR command and I got what I needed. I will most CERTAINLY be leaving a donation if that helps you guys. Really truly appreciate it!